# ModelState.IsValid does not update once I change input fields to valid inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a form "MovieForm" for adding movies to database. When I fill out all required inputs and press save button, movie gets added normally to database. If I first leave one or more required inputs empty and then press save, I get DataAnnotations error messages, "ModelState.isValid" becomes false and redirects me the same form which I'm already at with this code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Movie movie)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {  
        return View("MovieForm");
    }

  //logic for saving movie 
}
```

and that's how it should be done. The problems occurs after this operation. Now, when I fill all the required inputs and press save button again, ModelState.IsValid didn't update and it's still false, so I get stuck in this if statement.

How can I reset it, so it checks again are requirements met?

Model:

```
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MovieID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Director { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Actors { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@using Cinema.Models
@model Cinema.Models.Movie

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Movies", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, "Title", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger col-md-4 form-control-static" })
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Director, "Director", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Director, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Director, "", new { @class = "text-danger col-md-4 form-control-static" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Actors, "Actors ", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Actors, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Actors, "", new { @class = "text-danger col-md-4 form-control-static" })
    </div>
</div>

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MovieID)

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save" />
        <a class="col-md-offset-1" href="/Movies/">cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: That is simply not possible unless you have other code causing the issue. Note also it should be `return View("MovieForm", movie);`

Comment: Well, I debugged and once the `ModelState.isValid` gets value `false`, it doesn't change/update it when object `movie` with all valid values is passed to `Save` action. I also tried adding movie like you suggested, but didn't fix the issue.

Comment: You have not shown any of the relevant code so we cannot possibly guess what mistakes you have made.

Comment: I'm not sure what code exactly you want me to show? Other than this action only thing related to it, is `MovieForm` itself.

Comment: Show you model and view. `ModelStateIsValid` cannot be `false` unless your model is invalid. But start by including `var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });` in your POST method to check exactly which property(s) are invalid

Comment: added model/view to OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149763/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mark-west).

Answer (score 0):

You can check error in ModelState object by expanding it in  debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Stephen's suggestion in his comment gives a very nice succinct way of filtering the ModelState to see what is causing errors. I did something similar (though rather longer winded) to combine them in a single string for easy viewing/copying/pasting. Try adding this to your controller:

```
    string modelErrors = GetModelStateErrors(ModelState);
```

That calls this method:

```
    public string GetModelStateErrors(ModelStateDictionary ms)
    {
        StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string k in ms.Keys)
        {
            if (ms[k].Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                errors.Append($"\n{k}:\n");
                foreach (var e in ms[k].Errors)
                {
                    errors.Append($"   {e.ErrorMessage}\n");
                }
            }
        }
        return errors.ToString();
    }
```